# Angular UI-Router: Open child state in parent view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I currently have the following problem:

I am creating an Ionic/Angular/Phonegap application, using UI-router, which is great, only one thing is still unclear to me:

I have a tabbed application like this:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab class="tabs-icon-only" icon="ion-android-favorite-outline" ui-sref="main.outfit">
        <ion-nav-view name="outfit-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab class="tabs-icon-only" icon="ion-bag" ui-sref="main.cart">
        <ion-nav-view name="cart-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab class="tabs-icon-only" icon="ion-information-circled" ui-sref="main.contact">
        <ion-nav-view name="contact-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab class="tabs-icon-only" icon="ion-person" ui-sref="main.user">
        <ion-nav-view name="user-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

The `Contact` page has a button that opens `Reviews`, with which another page needs to be loaded inside the `Contact` page, which has `Contact` as a parent. To be clear: if I navigate to /contact/reviews, it should indicate the back button in the nav-bar, because it has parent `Contact`.

This is a part of my routes.js:

```
$stateProvider

.state("main", {
    url: "/main",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    defaultChild: 'main.outfit'
})

.state("main.outfit", { 
    url: "/outfit",
    cache: false,
    views: {
        'outfit-tab': {
            templateUrl: "views/outfit/outfit.html",
            controller: "OutfitIndexCtrl"
        }   
    },
    defaultChild: 'main.outfit.musthaves'
})

.state('main.outfit.basics', {
    url: "/basics",
    views: {
        'basics-tab': {
            templateUrl: "views/outfit/outfit.basics.html",
            controller: "OutfitBasicsCtrl"
        }   
    }
})

.state('main.outfit.musthaves', {
    url: "/musthaves",
    views: {
        'musthaves-tab': {
            templateUrl: "views/outfit/outfit.musthaves.html",
            controller: "OutfitMusthavesCtrl"
        }   
    }
})

.state('main.outfit.sale', {
    url: "/sale",
    views: {
        'sale-tab': {
            templateUrl: "views/outfit/outfit.sale.html",
            controller: "OutfitSaleCtrl"
        }   
    }
})

.state('main.contact', { 
    url: '/contact',
    views: {
        'contact-tab': { 
            templateUrl: "views/contact/contact.html",
            controller: "ContactCtrl"
        }   
    }
})

.state('main.contact.reviews', {
    url : '/reviews',
    views: {
        'contact-tab': { 
            templateUrl: "views/contact/review/review.html",
            controller: "ReviewCtrl"
        }   
    }
})
```

When I now click the button, nothing happens.. Below the code for the button.

```
<a ui-sref="main.contact.reviews" class="review-button">
    Klantenbeoordeling
</a>
```

What am I doing wrong here?